# Can we write NDEF message to Android HCE?

Tags: android, ios, hce, nfc-p2p, core-nfc

I have read the [Android HCE document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce#java) on google developer site. However, the whole document only told us how a NFC reader can read the HCE. So, I want to ask whether android HCE supports 'WRITE' action i.e. writing a NDEF message to HCE by an iPhone with CoreNFC function?